# Response data section is blank in J-meter

Tags: jmeter

In case of **POST** method I am not getting any response under Response Data section, while I did not receive any error in my test plan.
This happens only for **Post and Get** method and for rest of the others it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Given your Test Plan name is "My First API Test Plan" my expectation is that you need to pass data a little bit differently.

1. Upgrade JMeter to [latest version which is 2.13](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi). It has new functionality, performance improvements, bug fixes, etc.
2. Remove everything from "Parameters"
3. Switch to "Body Data" tab
4. Insert your JSON payload there
5. Make sure that your HTTP Header Manager is configured to send `Content-Type` header with the value of `application/json`

More details and tips in [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmitri T, it really helps me a lot.